# What is the etymology of the word, "own."

Tags: english

Dictionaries offer no etymogy on the word, "own."  A search for etymogy of the word comes up wanting.  Does anyone know the etymology of "own"?

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=own

Comment: Why was this question put on hold?

Comment: Because there are plenty of etymological resources available on the web for those who are willing to look for them.

Answer (score 1):

The word is related to German *eigen*, Norwegian *egen* and *eie* etc. In Proto-Germanic it has been reconstructed as *aiganaz.